# Django Geoposition - customize admin widget

Tags: django, django-geoposition

I'm trying to remove a field from the [django-geoposition](http://django-geoposition.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#) admin widget. This field:
[image]

I tried going to the source `site-packages/geoposition/static/geoposition/geoposition.css` and adding `display:none` to the relevant css class:

```
.geoposition-search {
    display: none;
    width: 30%;
}
```

That didn't work. How can I customize this widget?